# Find values which are present in all columns in a Cable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like a SQL Server query which finds the Values in a cell which fills multiple columns. For example, if I have table

```
 ID     Value1    Value2     Value3
 1        2        NULL      NULL 
 1       NULL      3         NULL 
 1       NULL      NULL       4
 1       3.4       NULL      NULL 
 2       NULL      3         NULL
 2       NULL      NULL      NULL
 3       NULL      NULL       91
```

As in the table above, only 2 of the columns can be filled at a time(First is ID and 2nd is either of Value1, 2 or 3) and ID can be repeated multiple times.

I want to return the ID as only `1` because `1` is the only ID that populates all the three other columns. 2 fills only Value2 and all the other values of 2nd iteration of 2 are NULL where as 3 is present only in Column Value3. Is there someway that I can find the Id's which fill all the other columns.

I would love to do this preferably without a cursor but I can go for cursor if it's compulsory. Thanks

EDIT

Desired Table:

`ID
 1`

The Statement should return only the filtered IDs which populate all the other columns.

Comment: add your desired output

Comment: @Rohit Raj,What is your desired result.

Comment: I have added the desired Table output

Comment: @RohitRaj,I posted answer based on your desired output check it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id, 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(value1) IS NOT NULL AND 
       MAX(value2) IS NOT NULL AND
       MAX(value3) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Will it work if the type of column Value2 is date and column type of Value3 is varchar?

Comment: I am getting an error in the `Column "Value1" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: @RohitRaj - Can you please try my line of code ? I tried that by creating a table.

Comment: @RohitRaj I think your attempting to select value1 in select list but forgot it to mentioned in Group By list, better way to post your original query so that easy for debug

Comment: The query is quite large.. Is there any way to DM you?

Answer (score 1):

Something for you try if you want some less lines of code:

```
select ID from dbo.Table_1  group by ID having count(Value1) > 0 AND count(Value2) > 0 AND count(Value3) >  0
```

Comment: How is this less lines of code than the other answer?  It's essentially the same query.